# How to extract FASTA sequence using sequence ID (shell script)

Tags: shell, fasta

I have the following sequences which is in a fasta format with sequence header and its nucleotides. 
How can I compare two files(Kcompare.pep and clade1i.txt) and extract the sequences with the same sequence header? 
Can anyone help me?

**Kcompare.pep**

```
>ztr:MYCGRDRAFT_45998
MAAPLHAEGPIRTPYTGVELLNTPYLNKGTAFPADERRVLGLTALLPTSVHTLDQQLQRA
WHQYQSRDNDLARNTFLTSLKEQNEVLYYRLVLDHLSEVFSIIYTPTEGEAIQRYSSLFR
>kal:KALB_5042
MTAEVAVVSDGSAIPGASPPATLPLLQDYAELVREHAGLSAVPLAVDSARLAAELCALPK
RFRAVFLTHTDPERAFQVQRAVAKAGGPLVITDQDTTAISLTASTLTTLARRGRSPSDSR
```

**clade1i.txt**

```
cpo:COPRO5265_0583
ble:BleG1_3845
kal:KALB_5042
```

**expected output**

```
>kal:KALB_5042
MTAEVAVVSDGSAIPGASPPATLPLLQDYAELVREHAGLSAVPLAVDSARLAAELCALPK
RFRAVFLTHTDPERAFQVQRAVAKAGGPLVITDQDTTAISLTASTLTTLARRGRSPSDSR
```

I tried to run this but no error or result appeared.

```
for i  in K*
   do
     echo $i

      awk -F ' ' '{print $1}' $i/$i.pep > Kcompare.pep
      mv Kcompare.pep $i

      awk -F '_' '{print $2":"$3"_"$4}' $i/firstClade.txt > $i/clade1i.txt
       awk 'NR==1{printf $0"\t";next}{printf /^>/ ? "\n"$0"\t" : $0}' $i/Kcompare.pep | awk -F"\t"  'BEGIN{while((getline k <"$i/clade1i.txt")>0)i[k]=1}{gsub("^>","",$0);if(i[$1]){print ">"$1"\n"$2}}' > $i/firsti.pep
    done
```

Comment: many solutions on biostars.org : https://www.biostars.org/p/84983/#84996

Comment: You can also try using [SAMtools](http://samtools.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[">"$0];next}/^>/{f=0;}($0 in a)||f{print;f=1}' clade1i.txt Kcompare.pep
```

Read the clade1i.txt file and store in an array as keys.
Read the Kcompare.pep. For every line beginning with '>', set a flag, and keep printing the lines till the next line beginning with '>' is encountered.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
while read l; do
  sed -n '/^>'"$l"'/,/^>|$/p' Kcompare.pep
done <clade1i.txt
```

- The `while` loop loops trough the `clade1i.txt` file line by line.
- `sed -n` suppresses auto print.
- `/regex/,/regex/` matches all from the first regex to the second.
- `p` prints matched lines.

Comment: Looping over a file and rereading the input file for each line is a frequent antipattern.  You could easily transform the inputs to a single `sed` script and then run that on the input file.  `sed 's%.*%/^>&$/,/^>|$/p' clade1i.txt | sed -n -f - Kcompare.pep`