# AWK - get value between two strings over multiple lines

Tags: awk

input.txt:

```
>block1
111111111111111111111
>block2
222222222222222222222
>block3
333333333333333333333
```

AWK command:

```
awk '/>block2.*>/' input.txt
```

Expected output

```
222222222222222222222
```

However, AWK is returning nothing. What am I misunderstanding?

Thanks!

Comment: There's no line containing `>block2>` in your input, so nothing could be printed.

Comment: There are multiple duplicates like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34670874/how-to-extract-fasta-sequence-using-sequence-id-shell-script though the ones I could quickly find would all include the >header line in the output. Changing this should oe trivial, anyway.

Comment: Why would you expect the output `222222` from a pattern which includes a non-optional match for `block2`, and no editing being applied to the matched text?  Do you expect `grep X` to output `Y`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to print the line after the line containing `>block2`, then you could use:

```
awk '/^>block2$/ { nr=NR+1 } NR == nr { print }'
```

Track the record number plus 1 when you find the match; when the current record number matches the remembered one, print the current record.

If you want all the lines between the line `>block2` and `>block3`, then you'd use:

```
awk '/^>block2$/,/^>block3/ {if ($0 !~ /^>block[23]$/) print }'
```

For all lines between the two markers, if the line doesn't match either marker, print it.  The output is the same with the sample data file.

Answer (score 2):

another `awk`

```
$ awk 'c&&c--; /^>block2/{c=1}' file
222222222222222222222
```

c specifies how many lines you want to print after the match.  If you want the text between two markers

```
$ awk '/^>block3/{exit} s; /^>block2/{s=1}' file
222222222222222222222
```

if there are multiple instances and you want them all, just change `exit` to `s=0`

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant:

```
$ awk '/>/{f=/^>block2$/;next} f' file
222222222222222222222
```